# ValueAnimator addUpdateListener repeated values

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

Method `addUpdateListener` runs multiple times with duplicate values.

I get log
0
0
1
1
2
2
and so on up to 100.

I want to see in the log
0
1
2
and so on up to 100.

```
ValueAnimator
    .ofInt(0, 100)
    .setDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(5).toMillis())
    .apply {
        doOnStart {}
        addUpdateListener {
            val progress = it.animatedValue as Int
            Log.d("tag", "$progress")
        }
        doOnEnd {}
    }.start()
```

Comment: Do you mean you get `00` on the same line of the log, or two duplicate log entries, two lines?

Comment: @Tenfour04 method addUpdateListener runs multiple times with duplicate values

Comment: This means you have somehow started this animator twice. It would be in code that you haven't shown here.

Comment: @Tenfour04
I'm running this code in a clean project, so it only runs in one place

Comment: Try printing a stack trace inside `doOnStart`, i.e. `doOnStart { Log.d("x", Thread.currentThread().stackTrace.joinToString("\n") }`. You might also try generating a random number right before declaring this value animator and including it in the log to see if this function was called twice.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Try to run this code which i mentioned above and you will see the same result

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the reasons are that `ValueAnimator` divides the passed values `ofInt()` by the duration of the animation, and inside himself he works with `Float`, and inside himself he turns into `Int`, so we get duplicate integers.

I decided to use a variable in which I store the passed values from `addUpdateListener` ​​and do a check `if`, also if you used `ValueAnimator` to show progress, you can try to use [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer) class